# networkd-dispatcher[807]: WARNING:Unknown index 470 seen, reloading interface list

Tags: networking, systemd-networkd

on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS with 4.15.0-177-generic

```
systemd-networkd[1535]: tun1: Link UP
systemd-networkd[1535]: tun1: Gained carrier
systemd-timesyncd[490]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
networkd-dispatcher[807]: WARNING:Unknown index 470 seen, reloading interface list
systemd-udevd[7055]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
systemd-networkd[1535]: tun1: Gained IPv6LL
```

More log context [is here](https://bin.disroot.org/?834586001553ed97#JvDBDt92A1PFgmyzQAktEbVCiMhXRvMbEywM3yGMHYz).
Redacted "ip a" output [is here](https://bin.disroot.org/?69002cb6d2edfb3a#J4qsG34pvQUUwtkfDeGv3Ni1nL2YAPtB3toaDSSowT1B).

I want to ask how to discover in which file and what particular thing is wrong? How to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this on 22.04 (same issue), this is known to work with credits to neoaggelos@canonical:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```